# Surface plot with 3 vectors Matlab

Tags: matlab, vector, plot

I need to be able to do a surface plot using data from 3 vectors. I found similar information, but no method seems to work with my data. My X and Y columns are evenly spaced, but not in increasing order. I tried different methods, but none of them seem to give me what I want, which is a simple surface linking close points together. I tried the following:

```
[X Y]=meshgrid(x,y);
Z=griddata(x,y,z, X,Y);
surf(X,Y,Z);
```

This is not exactly what I want, because it creates a surface at z=0 and makes it look more like a volume plot than just a surface. It also runs very slowly on my computer (probably from creating all the gridpoints). If I could get something that doesn't require as much memory it would be ideal (my vectors have about 20k values each), but this is not a necessity.

***Edit: I also tried using the scatteredInterpolant method found  [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/interpolating-scattered-data.html),but the function doesn't seem to be recognized by MATLAB and I get this error:

```
Undefined function 'scatteredInterpolant' for input arguments of type 'double'.
```

Also here is an image of my problem:
[image: here]

You can see that we can't see under the surface, there is some z=0 plane blocking it.

If you have anything for me, any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit 2: I added sample [vectors](https://www.dropbox.com/s/77usqkp20c981v4/Vectors.txt), they're my x,y and z values from left to right.

***Edit 3: Here's an image of the triangulation I get. As you can see some points are being ignored for some reason, which gives those long and weird looking blue triangles.

[image]

Mike

Comment: Does it help if you do `Z(~Z)=NaN`? Or what if you use a different `method` as described in `doc griddata`? Otherwise please post some sample code and vectors to fully replicate the problem.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin When I do Z(~Z)=NaN I get a [flatter bottom](http://imgur.com/qg8PMOm) but I still can't see through it, it closes it and forms a volume. My vectors are quite big, I'll try to find a way to link them.

Comment: Are you sure your data doesn't actually contain the low values that are plotted? What is the minimum z where the x and y value are between 0.8 and 1.2? Also, don't forget to try the different griddata options.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin Yes, when doing a scatter plot, we can clearly see that there are no points under the surface. I tried all methods in griddata and they all look similar. Is there any way to do it without using a grid? Is there no options that just looks at scattered points and tries to link them with a surface if they're close enough from one another? The grid will make the edges squares and it's not really desireable/ The delaunay method almost achieves that but there seems to be an error with the triangulation, which gives weird links, colors, and the same z=0 plane problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you have points which are described by vectors, and you want to plot them you could always use a Delauny triangulation. The function in matlab is called [Tri=delauny(X,Y,Z)](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/delaunay.html). The data generated by this function can be shown with either [trimesh(Tri,X,Y,Z)](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/trimesh.html) or [trisurf(Tri,X,Y,Z)](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/trisurf.html). Keep in mind trisurf is only for 3D data. If you want to adjust the transparancy of plots in your graph use the [alpha](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/alpha.html) setting.

I hope this helps

Comment: After trying trimesh on my data, I get something that looks like [this](http://imgur.com/Nj8U08g). We can see lines that cross from under the surface. The trisurf looks good but I still get that plane at z=0 coming, I'm guessing, from the lines I see in trimesh.

Comment: Sorry for my slow reply, I was out for the weekend. If I understand you correctly you wish to get rid of the triangles in the z=0 plane. This can be easily done by identifying which triangles describe this area. The trisurf command has the option of coloring specific triangles with a vector (let's call it C as in the help), trisurf(Tri,X,Y,Z,C). With C you can go around and identify the specific triangles. When identified, make a new array Tri2, which is the same as Tri without the offending triangles. Then do trisurf(Tri2,X,Y,Z). It's a bit clunky but it's hard to predict the triangles

Comment: Another, more generic way, would be to write an algorithm which tests the z component of every vertice of each triangle. If all vertices have z component = 0 it describes the z=0 plane and can be removed.

Answer (score 2):

As conventional methods seem to fail, I would suggest you to do it manually.

1. Create a `Z` matrix full of `NaN` values. The size of the matrix should be dependant on your `x` and `y` values.
2. Loop over all occuring `x`,`y`, pairs and put their (average?) `z` value in the right position of your `Z` matrix.
3. Loop over all `NaN` values and interpolate their value. Perhaps using `filter2`.
4. Use `surf` to plot the resulting surface

Comment: Thanks for answering. I really don't quite follow though, what do you mean "put their z value in the right position"? My vectors x,y,z are already ordered such that (x(i),y(i),z(i)) form the point I want to plot (scatter plot works fine). Also how can one interpolate NaN values if they don't have values by definition? Thanks again it's very appreciated.

Comment: @MikeNelson What I tried to say was: The griddata approach generates a `Z` matrix consisting of occuring values and interpolations. Try to create this matrix yourself somehow. Perhaps by starting only with occurring values and then doing your own interpolations.

Answer (score 2):

To me it looks like you just need to sort your data before plotting.

Here is an example which I believe is similar to your case (since I could not download your data).

```
x = [2 1 4 3 -1 -3 -4 -2];
y = [1 2 3 4 -1 -2 -3 -4];
z = 32 - x.*x - y.*y;

[X1 Y1] = meshgrid(x,y);
Z1 = 32 - X1.*X1 -Y1.*Y1; 
surf(X1,Y1,Z1)

aux = sort([x;y],2);
x = aux(1,:);
y = aux(2,:);

[X2 Y2] = meshgrid(x,y);

Z2 = 32 - X.*X - Y.*Y;
figure()
surf(X2,Y2,Z2)
```

The first figure results in a very problematic surface:[image: figure 1 (unsorted plot)]

The second figure contains the desired surface:[image: figure 2 (sorted plot)]